# A free pack of pantyliner if you could guess the number

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, password

At the opening of a new pantyliner shop, the manager would give its customers a free pack of pantyliner if they could guess the number of a word given.

> Angie came and asked a word, the manager said "*Pluto*",
>  then she
>   answered "94". Angie got a free pantyliner.
>  Angela came, the
>   manager said "*Uranus*", 
> and she answered "92". Angela got a free
>   pantyliner too.
>  Mila came, the manager said "*Mercury*",
>   
> and she answered "88". But Mila **got nothing**.
>  Cheril came,
>   the manager said "*America*", 
> then she answered "95". Then Cheril
>   got a free pack of pantyliner too.
>  Rosy came, the manager said
>   "*Europe*", 
> Rosy replied a number. Rosy also got a free pack of
>   pantyliner.

What did Rosy say, so she got the prize?
How to get the intended number ?

Comment: Dude, wtf?! Could you not have chosen something else to give away free? This sounds quite ... disturbing.

Comment: @Mawg, the pantyliner is actually related / a hint. Although I suspect a hint by someone who is not female and/or doesn't have English as a first language, because the connection isn't quite as direct as it could have been.

Comment: Maybe they simply got the pantyliner depending on whether there was anyone nearby who would laugh at the bizzarre situation or not, and the guess was just to distract.

Comment: What @Vicky said. Pantyliners are actually a hint *away* from the intended term (they're mainly used when that term does not apply).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

She replied:

> 63, the atomic number of Europium.

Mila should have said:

> 80 (Not 88, which is the orbital period of the planet)

Additional notes:

Names:

> I've been trying to find a link between the names and the elements. Uranium + Angela had an immediate hit on google for a collection of uranium deposits (Angela Pamela), but I couldn't find any links for the others.

Pantyliner:

> As noted by [Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan), this gives a connection in the form of "period"

Comment: Very fast. Can you explain why I use pantyliner in the puzzle?

Comment: @JamalSenjaya Yeah, having had a technical education the idea immediately sprung into my mind upon seeing this. Not sure regarding the pantyliner - googling the combination gave some... interesting sites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the connection is the word "period".

Comment: ... I guess I should have seen that.